# Trigger for user or logical permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I would like to apply write/delete/update permissions on my tables but by applying a logic.

> If a user has write/delete/update permission OK.
>
> If a user have no write/delete/updat permission must write/delete/updat to another table with a
>   logic operation on INSERTED/DELETED SQL Table

I have some triggers on my tables (most of its FOR INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE).
I don't want to change all triggers and make its INSTEAD OF and write OR NOT on tables based on user credential/property and there apply my logic.

There are another way to do that for example "Logical Triggers" or "Logical Permissions"?

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You want to apply permission roles to your tables in the form of a trigger without altering the existing triggers on your tables?

Comment: Exactly. I want to define a logical box where is defined it

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot have "one trigger to rule them all" in sql server (as noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174066/sql-server-create-single-trigger-that-runs-for-all-tables-in-the-database)). Your only option would be to put a trigger on every table and then set the priority of your role trigger so it executes before any other triggers. That, or simply add your role code before the rest of the trigger code in every trigger.